# Can (should) I include elements of TO_CHAR, CONCAT and FM in the same select statement?

Tags: sql, oracle, select, concatenation, number-formatting

I'm following up on a previous post that successfully generated an Oracle `SELECT` statement.  From within that prior script I now need to

- concatenate two different fields (numeric values for 3-digit area codes and 7-digit phone numbers), then
- format the resulting column as XXX-XXX-XXXX

but my attempts at using `TO_CHAR`, `CONCAT` (or `||` I have tried doing the concatenation both ways), and `FM` in the same line result in invalid number or invalid operator errors (depending on how I've rearranged the elements in the line) painfully reminding me that my barely-elementary scripting shows a significant lack understanding of proper use and syntax.

The combination of `TO_CHAR` and `CONCAT` (`||`) successfully produces a 9-digit string, but I'm trying to attain as result formatted as XXX-XXX-XXXX from the following (I've edited out the lines from the original script for data elements not relevant to this particular question; nothing in the original query is nested, it just selects several fields and has a series of left joins linking on a common UID field in different tables)

```
select distinct
  cn.dflt_id StudentIdNumber,
  to_char (p.area_code || p.phone_no) Phone,
from
  co_name cn
  left join co_v_name_phone1 p on cn.name_id = p.name_id
order by cn.dflt_id
```

Would anyone offer helpful advice on attaining the desired XXX-XXX-XXXX formatting in the resulting Phone column?  My attempts with variants of 'fm999g999g9999' have thus far not been successful.

Thanks,

Scott

Comment: Can you please post the schema (as `CREATE TABLE` statement) and sample data (as `INSERT INTO` statements)? That would make it easier to figure out what's going on there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few options that crossed my mind; have a look, pick the one you find the most appropriate. If you still have problems, post your own test case.

- RES2 is a simple concatenation of substrings that have a `-` in between
- RES3 uses format mask with an adjusted NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS for *thousands*
- RES4 concatenates area code (which is OK by itself) with regular expression that splits a string into two parts; the first has `{3}` characters, and the second one has `{4}` of them

By the way, are area codes really *numbers*? No leading zeros?

---

```
SQL> with test (area_code, phone_number) as
  2    (select 123, 9884556 from dual union
  3     select 324, 1254789 from dual
  4    )
  5  select
  6    to_char(area_code) || to_char(phone_number) l_concat,
  7    --
  8    substr(to_char(area_code) || to_char(phone_number), 1, 3) ||'-'||
  9    substr(to_char(area_code) || to_char(phone_number), 4, 3) ||'-'||
 10    substr(to_char(area_code) || to_char(phone_number), 7)
 11    res2,
 12    --
 13    to_char(to_char(area_code) || to_char(phone_number),
 14            '000g000g0000', 'nls_numeric_characters=.-') res3,
 15    --
 16    to_char(area_code) ||'-'||
 17    regexp_replace(to_char(phone_number), '(\d{3})(\d{4})', '\1-\2') res4
 18  from test;

L_CONCAT      RES2          RES3          RES4
------------- ------------- ------------- -------------
1239884556    123-988-4556   123-988-4556 123-988-4556
3241254789    324-125-4789   324-125-4789 324-125-4789

SQL>
```

Comment: Fabulous!  Thank you Littlefoot, both for editing my OP and for the code suggestions.  My specific problem was getting the desired output format.  The RES3 option resulted in the same ORA-01722: invalid number error that I'd been getting prior to my post (w/the cursor flashing between the concatenation pipes).  However, RES4 absolutely did the trick.  I browsed the data and both area_code and phone_no are defined as varchar2. Perhaps the original developers anticipated characters other than numbers might be entered in those fields?  Thanks again. -- Scott